# Calculated column, when does it recalculate?

Tags: 2013, calculated-column

A calculated column refreshes its content when an item is created or edited, so far so good. However, when an item is displayed in a list view, is the result of the calculation updated or not?

I have a list control for visits, and I need to check the date expired for a visit, and for this I have calculated column to help me, this column must update its content automatically.

Comment: You could use a JSLink template for the field, it can do calculations on display :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A calculated column only updates when the item is edited, not displayed.

Comment: Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use some JavaScript to display an "expired" visual cue, but it will not map to any flag or value in your list metadata (so it's purely for show).

In SP2013, use the JSLink parameter to hook a template override. See for example:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a
http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/Blog/Post/10/Introduction-to-Client-Side-Rendering-in-SharePoint-2013

which are similar to what you want to accomplish.